# Let $N$ be a number such that $\gcd(N,N+2)=2$ and $N+1$ is not divisible by $3$, is $N+1$ prime?

Tags: number-theory

Does anyone have a counterexample to the statement:

> Let $N$ be a natural number such that $\gcd(N,N+2)=2$ and $N+1$ is not divisible by $3$, then $N+1$ is prime.

Comment: I forgot the criterion of N+1 not being divisible by 3 in an earlier question, I was quite silly ...  Guy

Comment: Try using the Euclidean Algorithm to get another equivalent condition to the $\gcd$ condition.

Comment: Is there a way to refine the conditions on N, so that N+1 is prime ?  Guy

Comment: "Is there a way to refine the conditions on N, so that N+1 is prime ?"  Nope.  (That'd be a prime generator and we don't have those yet.)

Answer (score 2):

N=24 would be a counter example. the GCF of 24 and 26 is 2,and 24+1 is not divisible by 3, but 24+1 is not prime

Answer (score 1):

N = 24, 34, 48, 54,  64, 76, 84, 90, ......  (N, N + 2) = 2 is true for all even numbers so this statement is all odd numbers that aren't divisible by 3 are prime.  Which is not true.  Not even a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\gcd(N, N + 2) = 2$ for any even $N$. So pick any odd, composite integer not divisible by $3$ and let that be $N + 1$.